# Проблема с Console.ReadLine | C#

Tags: c#

Пишу простой код, в котором пользователь вводит два числа, но когда в консоли пишу для первой переменной, допусти, 5 и нажимаю Enter, программа заканчивается и не дает ввести вторую. В чем проблема?

```
            Console.Write("Enter first number: ");
            int first = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
            Console.Write("Enter second name: ")
            int second = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
            first = second;
            second = first;
            Console.WriteLine("The first number is {0} and the second number is {1}", first, second);
```

На строке "int second" во время дебага также выдает ошибку " ; expected"

Comment: "...econd name: ")" - нет точки с запятой в конце

Comment: Опечатки в коде, он даже не скомпилируется, не то что не заработает. Ну и документацию по `.Read()` стоило бы почитатт прежде чем использовать. Ведь вас этому никто не учил, верно? Что строки `first = second; second = first;` делают - тоже загадка, но этот код тоже нерабочий. А какую задачу решаете, не пояснили.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно заменить "Console.Read()" на "Console.ReadLine()".

"Console.Read()" читает ровно один символ. Таким образом, ваша программа читает два: 5 и Enter - и заканчивается.